# Python Decorator Type Hinting

Tags: python, mypy, python-decorators, type-hinting

Consider the following code:

```
from functools import wraps
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

class my_class():

    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = ConnectHandler()

    def validate_connection():
        @wraps(func)
        def inner(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if self.connection is None:
                raise Exception(
                    f"No connection to {self.name}({self.ip}):22\n"
                )
            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)

        return inner


    @validate_connection
    def send_command(self, *args, **kwargs) -> Union[str, list[Any], dict[str, Any]]:
        return self.connection.send_command(*args, **kwargs, read_timeout=60)
```

What would be the proper way to type hint the `validate_connection()` method and please explain how you figured it out.

Currently MyPy gives me the following error on the `@validate_connection` line

```
Argument 1 to "validate_connection" has incompatible type "Callable[[my_class, VarArg(Any), KwArg(Any)], str | list[Any] | dict[str, Any]]"; expected "my_class"
```

Comment: You're missing the `func` parameter in the definition of `validate_connection`: `def validate_connection(func: Callable) -> Callable:`

Comment: @Barmar hmmmm when I do that I get a new error on the first line of the validate_connection() method ```Self argument missing for a non-static method (or an invalid type for self)```

Comment: `validate_connection()` should be `@staticmethod` since it's not an instance method.

Comment: Really, it shouldn't be any sort of method - it should be placed outside the class.

Comment: @Barmar could you explain how I would go about doing that?

Comment: Just put `@staticmethod` before the definition. Similar to the way you put `@wraps` before `inner`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would pull the decorator out into a top level function, and then add an explicit typehint to `self`. Then you can make a typvar for the function argument, which will ensure the resulting method on the class maintains its original signature.

There is a cast in this example, and it does make the assumption that it will always be used on a specific class (assumes self is "MyClass"), but it does simplify the typehinting greatly.

```
from functools import wraps
from typing import Any, TypeVar, Callable, cast, List

Func = TypeVar("Func", bound=Callable[..., Any])


def validate_connection(func: Func) -> Func:
    @wraps(func)
    def inner(self: "MyClass", *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
        if self.connection is None:
            raise Exception
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)

    return cast(Func, inner)


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.connection = None

    @validate_connection
    def send_command(self, foo: int, bar: str) -> List[str]:
        return []
```

Examples with mypy output proving validation:

```
MyClass().send_command(1, "2").append("3")
# No error :)

MyClass().send_command(1, "2").append(3)
# error: Argument 1 to "append" of "list" has incompatible type "int"; expected "str"  [arg-type]

MyClass().send_command(1, 2).append("3")
# error: Argument 2 to "send_command" of "MyClass" has incompatible type "int"; expected "str"  [arg-type]
```

Note, you could also choose to make this an `@staticmethod` instead, all of the rest still applies

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.connection = None

    @staticmethod
    def validate_connection(func: Func) -> Func:
        @wraps(func)
        def inner(self: "MyClass", *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
            if self.connection is None:
                raise Exception
            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)

        return cast(Func, inner)

    @validate_connection
    def send_command(self, foo: int, bar: str) -> List[str]:
        return []
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This was really helpful and I understand much better now. If possible, could you explain the advantages/disadvanteges of your first top level function and the second @staticmethod

Comment: @Net-worker not too much difference. Static methods are not associated with an instance of the class, but to the class definition, similar to how a top level function is not associated with an instance of a class. I find it much easier to spot that difference right away if I see the function not in the class at all. That helps me months later when I come back to the code and try to remember what I wrote :)

Comment: To that note, using `@staticmethod` to me, is just an indicator that I probably should have written a function instead of a class method in the first place. No need to add extra layers for style purposes.

Comment: I can however get behind the argument that using a static method shows that it is related to this class, and as such, should only be used by this class. To each their own, its a very minor nitpick. For whatever you do prefer, just stay consistent. That makes the code easier to read by future contributors (or yourself).

Comment: That makes complete and total sense. Thanks so much for answering! I have a much better understanding of how these work now!!